# How can we find the element of the adapter class in fragment?

Tags: android, listview

I want to find the item of the adapter class in the fragment class. Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

This is my `getView()` method :-

```
     public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (view == null) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.Dish_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameofdish);
                viewHolder.dish_description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dishdescription);
                viewHolder.Dish_rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rateofdish);
                viewHolder.item_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_item);



                viewHolder.tv_Number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_add_sub);
                viewHolder.mBtnAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
                viewHolder.mBtnMinus = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
```

I want to find textview(viewHolder.tv_Number) in the fragment class,it can be possible ?

Comment: What you want to do with that text view? give brief idea so we can help you

Comment: i am making a cart ! and i want to get the quantity from the textview and multiply with the amount !

Comment: you can do using by your model class

Comment: can u tell me how can i do this ! shailesh limbadiya

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a public method in the adapter that returns the ViewHolder to the Fragment, but I would ask why you would want to do that? The adapter is supposed to be solely responsible for handling the translation of the data provided by your fragment into the View elements.

If you want to do something with that TextView, I heavily suggest you amend the data item from the fragment, notify the adapter that the dataset has changed and subsequently ensure that whatever needs to be done to the view is done within getView or whatever binding/populate method you're using in the adapter.